# Is there a VB.NET equivalent to C#'s "using static"?

Tags: vb.net

For instance, in C# I could say:

`using static System.Math;`

which would let me call static methods of that class without a qualifier:

`var c = 300 * Pow(10, 9)`

Is there anything like this in VB.NET?

Comment: `Imports System.Math`. All static methods. With `Option Strict On`, use the explicit type declaration (`Dim c As Double = ...`) if `c` is a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB.NET you can just use Imports System.Math

```
Imports System.Math

Public Class Test
    Dim c = 300 * Pow(10, 9)
End Class
```

Comment: Oh that's interesting, so I guess the feature actually predates C#'s `using static`?

Comment: I'm guessing it has always been supported in VB.NET.  Support for importing "elements" as opposed to namespaces goes back to at least 2015 when this article was created: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type

Comment: This also works with `Imports System.Console` so you only have to write `WriteLine("Hello") `vs `Console.WriteLine("Hello")`- similar to using C#: `Using static System.Console`;